# How to show client a domainless site without altering hosts file or using 'serverip/~accountname'?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, vps

We have updated VPSs and apparently the latest version of PHP(?) does not allow you to use the servers ip /~accountname as a way to view a site that does not yet have a domain name associated to it, eg:

```
122.221.10.23/~newsite
```

or

```
ourhostingserver.com/~newsite
```

We can view it from our computers by altering the hosts file, adding something like:

```
122.221.10.23 www.newsite.com.au
122.221.10.23 newsite.com.au
```

but its not very  practical to ask our not-tech-savvy clients to go altering their host files.

Does anyone know of a way we can show our clients these sites using some kind of temporary domain name or similar?

Comment: This is not a PHP feature, it is a server configuration that allows one to use the way you described to access a site without DNS. So, you need to copy the web server configuration from the old VPS.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you could do this.

**Have a staging server**

So you must be having your own domain. 
Use this nomenclature for hosting the staging work -

> client.yourdomain.com

This is done using VirtualHosts in Apache. If you have your own VPS, this should be a breeze.

Another alternative for this would be to use **folder structures** -

> yourdomain.com/client

Comment: I agree that this is a case where a domain name is required. They can re-use an existing domain name (or register a new domain name) and create a sub-domain for the customer.